# While creating an AMI the ansible_distribution_version for a specific OS the value should be picked dynamically instead of mentioning it manually

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ami, packer

Currently when we are creating an AMI in AWS using packer then we Read variables for detected OS from `/vars/var_<linux-os>.yml` files

example

```yaml
- name: read variables for ubuntu 20.04
  include_vars: "vars_os_ubuntu-20.yml"
  when: ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" and ansible_distribution_version == "20.04"
```

As you can see in the above code, we have specifically mentioned the Ubuntu version, now, if the version changes to 22.04 or let say 24.04, how can we set this value dynamically?
Is there any way where we can implement the same in Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in the `include_vars`:

```yaml
- name: >-
    Include variables for {{ ansible_distribution }} 
    {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
  include_vars: >-
    vars_os_{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}-
    {{- ansible_distribution_version.split('.')[0] }}.yml
```

This would, in my Alpine container, give me, when running the playbook in verbose mode — so, with a `-v` flag:

```
TASK [Include variables for Alpine 3.15.4] ***********************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts: {}
  ansible_included_var_files:
  - /usr/local/ansible/vars_os_alpine-3.yml
```

And so, as stated by the verbose message, include the file *vars_os_alpine-3.yml*, which match the pattern in your requirement.